# NDK Standalone Compiler

Tags: android

I create two standalone ndk compiler arm and x86, and set environment variable of windows, let's say CUSTOM_NDK. When I put arm path to CUSTOM_NDK, and under cygwin command line to compile such as `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c xxx.cpp`, it's working fine. But when I put x86 path to CUSTOM_NDK, close cygwin and reopen it to ensure the env variable is loaded, every time I launch `i686-linux-android-gcc -c xxx.cpp`, it gives me the following error:

```
i686-linux-android-gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I use `i686-linux-android-gcc --print-search-dirs`, it gives me the following which seems correct to me

```
$ i686-linux-android-gcc -print-search-dirs
install: c:\dev\custom-android-toolchian_x86\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/
programs: =c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/
libraries: =c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/lib/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/lib/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../sysroot/lib/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../sysroot/lib/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/4.6/;c:/dev/custom-android-toolchian_x86/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I see a bunch of **toolchian** rather than **toolchain** -- did you misspell something?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added the path to env variable. I think it doesn't matter. When I go to android-ndk-r9b\toolchains\x86-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin, and directly run i686-linux-android-gcc -c xxx.cpp, it gives me the same error.